# Module 'btford.socket-io' is not available

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

```
let groupModule = angular.module('app.group',['btford.socket-io']);
```

I have included socket.js and /socket.io/socket.io.js as well. Still getting this error. Completed all the steps in ReadMe but still getting this error.

[Github repo](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io)

I am trying to use angular-socket-io.

Comment: Please share the error deatils?

Comment: Show us your index.html